# Is it possible to rename the metadata attribute of a SQLAlchemy declarative base?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to set up a database with a few specific fields (and I can't move away from the specification). One of the fields would be a column called `metadata`, but `sqlalchemy` prevents that:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Attribute name 'metadata' is reserved for the MetaData instance when using a declarative base class.
```

Is there a decent workaround for this? Do I need to monkeypatch the `declarative_base` function to rename the `metadata` attribute? I couldn't find an option to rename that attribute in the [api docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html).

Here's some example code that will fail with the above error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer


class CustomBase(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

DBBase = declarative_base(cls=CustomBase)


class Data(DBBase):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    metadata = Column(Integer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(dir(Data()))
```

Comment: The column name and the attribute name do not have to be the same.

Comment: Very true! I should also mention I'm also using `pydantic` to do JSONschema translation, so I actually want the attribute name to be `metadata`.

Comment: Well, then you have to pick one requirement that is less important than the others.

Answer (score 7):

You can use like:

```py
class Data(DBBase):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # metadata = Column(Integer)
    metadata_ = Column("metadata", Integer)
```

The constructor of `Column` class has a `name` parameter. You can find it from https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column

> The name field may be omitted at construction time and applied later

In other words, you could write a name as you want originally.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I recently faced the same problem and managed to find a solution.

For SQLAlchemy 2.0+ you can just declare the column right after the model declaration:

```py
class Data(DBBase):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

Data.metadata = Column(Integer)
```

**DOCS:** https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#appending-additional-columns-to-an-existing-declarative-mapped-class